# append is not working when i upload image and append image object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loopback, form-data

append function is not working when i append image object in formdata it's display blank object.i want upload file so i need to attached it.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file:null
    };
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
  }
submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit
    this.fileUpload(this.state.file)
    })
  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] })
  }
  fileUpload(file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file)
    console.log(formData,'-----------------------')
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your submit function is illegal, there's something wonky going on with the brackets.

Comment: Are u sure the event has `files`? Maybe you need to grab the `<input type="file"/>`

Comment: yes i am 100% sure my input type is 'file' <Input type="file" id="vat" placeholder="icon" onChange={this.onChange} />

Answer (score 0):

With FormData, `console.log()` doesn't work. If you want to check if the formData has your file then you need to use `formData.get('file')` and then you can log it to see your file.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Try sending the request without headers. When we use formdata it sets the header content-type itself. So please remove it and try it again and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "[multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)" middleware to view the appended image in formdata .
This worked in my case.